# What do these ARM assembly instructions do?

Tags: assembly, arm

I came across these ASM instructions recently and am trying to figure out what they do. I went through a few ARM assembly books (such as [THIS](http://www.toves.org/books/arm/)) and was able to figure out what a couple of instructions do.

For instance, `MRS (Move to Register from Status)` copies status from the `PSR (Program Status Register)` register to `%0` (which I believe is register 0).

I am not able to understand what `: "=r" (Cs)` and other similar instructions do.

```
UINT32 Cp;
if((Cp & 0x1) == 0)
{
   UINT32 Cs;
   __asm
   (
     " MRS %0, PSR\n"
     "BIC %1, %2, #0x80\n"
     "cpsie i"
           : "=r" (Cs), "=r" (Cp)
           : "r" (Cs)
   );
}
```

Can someone please explain?

Edit 1: This is inside a GlobalLock release function. `cpsie i` enables the interrupts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't (just) assembler, it's inline assembler embedded in C code. Presumably there's some context around this code, or where you found it, which should suggest this.

See, for example, the [GCC Extended Asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) docs.

This builtin emits the assembler (which you've already identified) in the middle of some C code, and also tells the compiler what the assembler did: specifically, which registers were used or damaged.

The last two lines indicate which variables are used in the assembler, and how they're affected

1. `"=r" (Cs)` - the variable `Cs` is used as an output register, called `%0` in the assembly code, and is overwritten
2. `"=r" (Cp)` - the variable `Cp` is used as an output register, called `%1` in the assembly code, and is overwritten
3. `"r" (Cs)` - Cs is used as an input register, called `%2` in the assembly code

Note that `%0/1/2` are just the positions of the entries in the input/output list, starting from zero.

Comment: Thanks Useless. Yes, this is inside a function that is supposed to clear a GlobalLock and as you have mentioned it seems to be wrong and is not working the way it is supposed to. I am trying to figure out what is wrong and trying to fix it. I will edit my question to add more context. I can't upvote your answer as I don't have the required reputation.

Comment: You have the interpretation of those lines wrong. The first line indicates both `Cs` and `Cp` are used as register outputs. The second line indicated `Cs` is also used as a register input.

Answer (score 0):

Those look like assembler directives. From the code you provided, it looks like you're trying to decipher the assembly language emitted by a compiler. Those "instructions" are likely telling the compiler back-end to emit opcodes appropriate to the target machine. This permits the front-end compiler to remain relatively simple, yet permit the compiler to emit (and optimize) specific instructions for particular targets.